# How to connect to postgres instance running in docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

**Update 1**
Needed to run the following:

```
root@8809a5d5cf76:/# psql -U x2 -d y2 --password
```

Starting `postgres` with this `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres:10.12
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ~/work/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  environment:      
    POSTGRES_USER: x2
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password1
    POSTGRES_DB: y2
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
```

`docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
8809a5d5cf76        postgres:10.12      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp              thebook_db_1
```

Trying to connect like so:

```
$ docker exec -it thebook_db_1 bash
root@8809a5d5cf76:/# psql -U x2
psql: FATAL:  database "x2" does not exist
```

What is wrong with the `POSTGRES_USER` in `docker-compse`?

Comment: Have a look at this thread https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/203#issuecomment-254162582. This might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `psql` try specifying the name of a database using the `-d` switch:

```
psql -U x2 -d y2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `POSTGRES_USER` in `docker-compose` should be fine. Your `psql` command needs to specify the name of the database to which you want to connect, `y2` in your example.

This could be done with the following command:

```
psql -U x2 y2
```